# Search by part of the date string from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date stored in the following format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS in mysql. I need to search all date by YYYYMM only.

Example row: `ID,TRANS_DATE,DATA ('2252','20190828195223','AUTHORISED')`

Expected: `select DATA where TRANS_DATE = 201908`

I want to write a query where TRANS_DATE = 201908

Comment: Try `SELECT data WHERE trans_date LIKE '201908%';`

Comment: should probably use one of the date\time types your database provides, gives you a lot more flexibility

Comment: Mysql gives you the CAST function which converts your column to DATETIME or DATE like so `CAST(TRANS_DATE AS DATETIME)`, but also @odan solution is quite good.

Comment: Thanks @odan it's perfect.